# FastAPI and Pydantic - ignore but warn when extra elements are provided to a router input Model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, python-3.11

This is the code I wrote

```
from typing import Any
from fastapi import APIRouter
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, ValidationError



class State(BaseModel):
    mode: str | None = None
    alarm: int = 0


class StateLoose(State):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='allow')


class StateExact(State):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')


def validated_state(state: dict) -> State:
    try:
        return StateExact(**state)
    except ValidationError as e:
        logger.warning("Sanitized input state that caused a validation error. Error: %s", e)
        return State(**state)


@router.put("/{client_id}", response_model=State)
def update_state(client_id: str, state: StateLoose) -> Any:
    v_state = validated_state(state.dict()).dict()
    return update_resource(client_id=client_id, state=v_state)


# Example State inputs
a = {"mode": "MANUAL", "alarm": 1}
b = {"mode": "MANUAL", "alarm": 1, "dog": "bau"}

normal = State(**a)
loose = StateLoose(**a)
exact = StateExact(**a)
```

From my understanding/tests with/of pydantic

- State "adapts" the input dict to fit the model and trows an exception only when something is very wrong (non-convertable type, missing required field). However, extra fields are lost.
- StateLoose, accepts extra fields and shows them by default (or with **pydantic_extra**)
- StateExact trows a ValidationError whenever something extra is provided

What I wanted to achieve is:

- Show the "State scheme as input" in the FastAPI generated Docs (this means having a State-like input in the "put function".
- Accept States that have extra elements but ignoring the extra elements (this means using State to remove extra args)
- Log a warning when extra elements are detected so that I can trace this since probably it means something went not as planned

To achieve this I was forced to create 3 different State classes and play with those. Since I plan to have lots of Models, I don't like the idea of having 3 versions of each and it feels like I am doing something quite wrong if it's so weird to accomplish.

**Is there a less redundant way to:**

- accept extra elements in a Model;
- use the Model as an input to FastAPI router.put;
- generate a warning;
- ignore extra elements and continue with the right ones?

Comment: You can use a `model_validator` with `before` to get access to the submitted values _before_ validation happen, so you can log any fields that you didn't expect; you can then configure your model to use `ignore` for `extra` so anything that doesn't match a parameter gets dropped. https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.BaseModel.model_fields should give you the fields defined on the model.

Comment: I honestly tried but without any real success in understanding how it works. Would you be able to write an example of how the small code above would look like? In that case I could also accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `model_validator` with `mode="before"` together with the field names from model - i.e. in your validator you see which fields got submitted and log those that you didn't expect.

Setting `extra='ignore'` as the `model_config` will also make sure that the extra fields gets removed automagically.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, model_validator


class WarnUnknownBase(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(extra='ignore')

    @model_validator(mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, values):
        expected_fields = set(cls.model_fields.keys())
        submitted_fields = set(values.keys())
        unknown_fields = submitted_fields - expected_fields
        
        if unknown_fields:
            print(f"Log these fields: {unknown_fields}")

        return values
        
        
class Foo(WarnUnknownBase):
    foo: int
    
    
app = FastAPI()

@app.put('/')
def put_it(foo: Foo):
    return foo
```

Example requests:

```bash
λ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"foo\": 42}" http://localhost:8008
{"foo":42}
λ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d "{\"foo\": 42, \"bar\": 13}" http://localhost:8008
{"foo":42}
```

As you can see, `bar` gets ignored when the Foo object is created.

The second request will output `Log these fields: {'bar'}` on the server side, while the first will keep quiet.

```bash
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49458 - "PUT / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Log these fields: {'bar'}
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49462 - "PUT / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

Comment: Wow, just tried it out and works like a charm. Thanks, it was really a good way to solve this.